# nodejs no me encuentra un dirección para recibir datos?

Tags: html, nodejs, jsp

Archivo app.js

```
   var express = require('express');
   var routes = require('./routes/index');
   var bodyparser = require("body-parser");
   var middleware = require('./routes/middleware')
   var programmers = require('./routes/programmers');
   var programmersModel = require('./models/model').programmersModel;
   var session = require('express-session');




   programmers.setModel(programmersModel);
   var app = express();
   app.use(express.static('public'));
   app.set('view engine','jade');
   app.use(bodyparser.json());
   app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

   app.use(session({

   secret:"user14",
   resave: false,
   saveUnitialized: false
   }));

   app.get('/', routes.index);
   app.post('/session', programmers.session);

   app.use('/*',middleware.middleware1);

   app.use('/app', middleware.middleware2);

   //app.get('/*', middleware.middleware3);
   app.get('/app/programmers', programmers.formulario);
   app.get('/app/programmers', programmers.index);
   app.get('/app/programmers/create', programmers.create);
   app.post('/app/programmers', programmers.store);
   app.get('/app/programmers/:id', programmers.show);
   app.get('/app/programmers/:id/edit', programmers.edit);
   app.post('/app/programmers/update/:id', programmers.update);
   app.post('/app/programmers/delete/:id', programmers.destroy);
   app.get('/app/close',programmers.close);
   app.listen(8080);

   console.log("listenIng http://localhost:8080");
```

Archivo programmers.js

```
   exports.atenderFormulario = function(req, res){                                               Programmers.findById(req.params.id, function(error, documento){ if (error) { res.send('Error al intentar ver el formulario.'); } else {

    res.redirect('/atenderFormulario.jsp',{
        programmers: documento
    });
}
   });
   };
```

Archivo middleware.js

```
   exports.middleware1 = function(req, res ,next){
   next();
   }
   exports.middleware2 = function(req,res,next){
   next();
   }
```

Archivo formulario.html

REGISTRO

|

```
</header>


<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper teallighten-1">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo">ARS-MUSIC</a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li>
                <a href="sass.html"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="badges.html">componentes</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/app/close">Cerrar Sesion</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>


           <h1>Guardar usuarios</h1>
           <form  action="/atenderFormulario.jsp" method="post" >
<div class="form-inline">

        <label for="NOMBRE">NOMBRE</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="Nombre" placeholder="NOMBRE" pattern="[ A-Za-z ]+"
               title="Este no parece un nombre válido"
               required>


        <label for="APELLIDO">APELLIDO</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" pattern="[ A-Za-z ]+"
               title="Este no parece un apellido válido"
               required id="Apellido" name="apellido"  placeholder="APELLIDO">

<br>
<br>


    <label for="USUARIO"> NOMBRE DE USUARIO</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  pattern="[ 0-9-A-Za-z ]+"
           title="Este no parece un nombre de usuario válido"
           required id="Nombus" name="user" placeholder="NOMBRE DE USUARIO">



    <label for="CONTRASEÑA">CONTRASEÑA</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="contraseña" name="pass"  placeholder="Password" pattern="[ 0-9-A-Za-z ]+"
           title="Este no parece una contraseña válida"
           required>

    <label for="edad">edad</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="number" id="edad" name="edad">

<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" value="masculino" id="test1" name="genero"  />
  <label for="test1">Masculino</label>
    <br>
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" value="FEMENINO" id="test2" name="genero"  />
    <label for="test2">Femenino</label>
</label>
<br>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Enviar">Registrar</button>
 <a>(href='/app/programmers') Cancelar </a>
```

[image: asi la carpeta de contenidos]

cuando oprimo el botón registar sale Cannot POST /atenderFormulario.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Caramba, no soy experto.  Sin embargo yo probe Angular-UI-Router y pude enrutar mas facil.  Documentate sobre eso y lo planteas asi.  De esta forma hay una mejor estructura segun la practica actual.  En vez de hacer cosas como  (href='/app/programmers') Cancelar , te propongo usando Angular UI Router un esquema como:

```
 var miapp = angular.module('miapp', ['ui.router']);
miapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
```

`

```
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/estado1");

    $stateProvider
        .state('estado1', {
            url: "/estado1",
            templateUrl: "plantilla1.html"
        })
        .state('estado2', {
            url: "/estado2",
            templateUrl: "plantilla2.html",
        })
        .state('estado3', {
            url: "/estado3",
            templateUrl: "plantilla3.html"
        }) 

});
```

Ahora el HTML:

```
<body>
<div ui-view></div>
<a ui-sref="estado1">
    <button class="" type="submit">Cancelar</button>
</a>
</body>
```